# laravel 5 ajax post 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: laravel

give this error

console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

messages.blade.php

```
<script>
    function getMessage(){            
       $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'getmsg',
          data:{dsf:'sdsadsda'},
          success:function(data){
             $("#msg").html(data.msg);
          }
       });
    }
</script>
```

routes

```
Route::get('ajax',function(){
   return view('test.messages');
});
Route::post('getmsg','TestController@index');
```

controller

```
public function index(){
    $msg = "This is a simple message.";
    return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
}
```

Comment: See in console what you are getting.. also check the logs in storage/logs

Comment: Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for error

Comment: i send token problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I think

url:'/getmsg',

in ajax call will solve your issue else give details about the console error